# second mutable borrow occurs here

Tags: rust

Estoy iniciando con rust y como practica necesito recorrer un vector y comprobar sus valores , si el valor / 2  = 0 entonces en ese momento agrego un valor cualquiera al vector; el problema es que al momento de hacer esa operacion me lanza el siguiente error:

```
8 |             v.push(32);
  |             ^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

este es mi codigo completo:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1,2,3];
    {
        for i in &mut v{
        println!("{}",i );
        if *i%2 == 0{

            v.push(32);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

El compilador de Rust es por lo general bastante explícito y claro a la hora de exponer los errores, si vemos la traza completa:

> ```
> error[E0499]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable more than once at a time
>  --> src/main.rs:8:13
>   |
> 4 |         for i in &mut v{
>   |                  ------
>   |                  |
>   |                  first mutable borrow occurs here
>   |                  first borrow later used here
> ...
> 8 |             v.push(32);
>   |             ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
> ```

En Rust solo puedes tener **una referencia mutable a un dato en particular en un ámbito (scope) particular**. Esto es así para impedir las llamadas "data races", que tiene lugar cuando varios punteros tienen acceso al mismo dato simultánemente y al menos uno puede mutar el dato sin que existan mecanismo de sincronización de por medio.

Lo que intentas hacer es peligroso en si mismo, llegando a lo que se conoce como la invalidación de iterador que implica el uso de iteradores mientras se modifica el conjunto de datos subyacente de alguna manera (su longitud).

Imaginemos que tu código compila, al encontrar un numero par agregas al final del vector otro numero par por lo que tendrías un ciclo teóricamente infinito  en el momento en el que un numero par existiera en el vector original.

Realmente el ciclo infinito no es el mayor problema, el problema es la asignación de nueva memoria para contener el vector creciente, que  podría llegar a generar un fallo de segmentación. Los vectores tienen una cierta cantidad de espacio asignado y como deben usar memoria contigua, si el vector crece más allá de este espacio es necesario realizar una nueva asignación de memoria copiando el vector en el nuevo fragmento y **liberando la memoria anterior, lo que ocasiona la invalidación de la referencia almacenada en el iterador**.

Para evitar esto Rust y su "inspector de prestamos" impide que puedas modificar un vector (entendiendo por mutar variar su tamaño). En tu caso **`v.push(32)` toma prestado `v` que ya fue prestado al iterador** y podría invalidarlo, pero Rust asegura que solo haya una referencia mutable a un objeto a la vez y también asegura que no haya referencias mutables a un objeto en el mismo ámbito que las referencias inmutables a ese objeto, evitando así las "data races".

Para hacer lo que quieres tienes varias opciones, una de ellas es clonar el vector e iterar sobre el clon:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];  

    for i in v.clone(){  
        if i % 2 == 0{
            v.push(32);
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso también es seguro usar indizado, aunque hay que ser cuidadoso en otros casos, por ejemplo si eliminamos elementos invalidamos índices generados por el rango:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];  
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        if v[i] % 2 == 0{
            v.push(32);
        }
    }
}
```